# nested LINQ query, error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am currently trying to do a nested query in linq, but I am receiving an error message:

```
var subcatquery = from categories in mydb.Categories
                  where categories.ParentId == null
                  select new
                  {
                      category = categories.Name,
                      subcat = (from sub in mydb.Categories
                                where sub.ParentId == sub.Id
                                select new
                                {
                                    subcatItem = sub.Name,
                                    subcatId = sub.Id
                                 })
                    };
```

Results View =`The type '<>f__AnonymousType0<subcatItem,subcatId>' exists in both 'myapplication.dll' and 'System.Web.dll'`

I can't underestand why.. if I remove the sub query and put it on it's own... it's perfectly fine.

the `subcat` type is a `collection<>`, is this where the problem is?

```
    class categoryGroup 
    {
        public string category;
        public Collection<subcategoryGroup> subcat;

    }
    class subcategoryGroup
    {
        public string subcatItem;
        public int subcatId;

    }
```

Comment: what you are trying to so in subcat??will you please elaborate it...i thought you might want inner join in subcat between ParentId and Id..isn't it?

Comment: in your sub query you get subcatitem name and subcatid and you use in both query same table name ??

Comment: @Rajpurohit Yes.. it is a relational table pointing to itself. I should point out I'm querying the same table.

Comment: I assume that the error you get is a compiler error. If I interpret it correctly there is a conflict between your own anonymous type and an anonymous type in `System.Web.dll`. Buy anonymous types are internal to the assembly where they are defined. So how is that possible? There must be some vital information missing in the question.

Comment: @MartinLiversage it is not a compiler error, it is in debug mode and when I look at the results view. I am not sure what I am missing here that is why I haven't found the problem.

Comment: After your edit: does that mean that you use named types now in stead of anonymous types? If so `subcat` should be an `IEnumerable<>`.

Answer (score 1):

In my project i am using sub query like this it's below

```
 var data = (from con in dbData.tblPresenters
                        where con.PresenterID == ID
                        select new
                        {
                            Name = con.Name,

                            Title = dbData.tblTitles.Where(x => x.TitleID == con.PresenterTitleID).FirstOrDefault()
                        }).ToList();
```

i think this will help you ....

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, the first 'new' anonymous class is conflicting with the second 'new' anonymous class because it's already created. I don't know what the solution is though...

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to define/name the types instead of keeping them anonymous,

```
var subcatquery = from categories in mydb.Categories
                   where categories.ParentId == null
                   select new categoryGroup()
                   {
                       category = categories.Name,
                       subcat = (from sub in mydb.Categories
                                 where sub.ParentId == sub.Id
                                 select new subcategoryGroup()
                                 {
                                     subcatItem = sub.Name,
                                     subcatId = sub.Id
                                  })
                     };
```

Comment: I have tried this, it does not allow me to compile. There is an error in this statement: select new subcategoryGroup()